# Database shared locks being acquired on database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking

I'm currently working on a system that suffers from timeout issues.. some appear to be related to long running queries that are locking frequently updated tables.

I recently ran sp_lock on the production server and noticed a lot of sessions that appear to be locking the whole database?

An example of the output:

spid: xxx
dbid: x
ObjId: 0
IndId: 0
Type: DB
Mode: S
Status: GRANT

Is this unusual? Surely we would be having bigger issues than intermittent timeouts if the whole db is being locked?

Comment: You can checkout articles .. [different techniques to identify blocking in sql server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2732/different-techniques-to-identify-blocking-in-sql-server/)  and  [how to isolate the current running commands in sql server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1811/how-to-isolate-the-current-running-commands-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @t_m Thanks for the info. At this point I'm just trying to actually get confirmation that I'm understanding the output of sp_lock correctly.

Comment: Don't normally use sp_lock and checked it on our DB and you are correct that all connection have Type = DB which is database lock but our DB doesn't have any issues with locks. You may want to look into DMV (Dynamic Management Views). In Documentation sp_lock will be removed in future [Msoft sp_lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187749.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't normally use sp_lock and checked it on our DB and you are correct that all connection have Type = DB which is database lock but our DB doesn't have any issues with locks. You may want to look into DMV (Dynamic Management Views). In Documentation sp_lock will be removed in future [Msoft sp_lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187749.aspx)

Comment: Sample using `sys.dm_tran_locks` ?